# Is possible responsive sap.m.dialog footer three buttons

Tags: responsive-design, sapui5

I am using a sap.m.Dialog and also want to use three buttons. For this I am using the buttons aggregation.
In this situation the problem is that it is not responsive on a phone. What can I do to fix this.

Below is an image of the problem

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAxeb.jpg)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVBK5.jpg)

Dialog Code

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">

    <Dialog title="{i18n>ARACBILGILERIEKLE}" draggable="true" stretch="{device>/isPhone}" verticalScrolling="true">
        <f:SimpleForm id="AracBilgileriSimpleForm"
            editable="false"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            labelSpanXL="3"
            labelSpanL="3"
            labelSpanM="3"
            labelSpanS="12"
            adjustLabelSpan="false"
            emptySpanXL="4"
            emptySpanL="4"
            emptySpanM="4"
            emptySpanS="0"
            columnsXL="2"
            columnsL="1"
            columnsM="1"
            singleContainerFullSize="false" >
            <f:content>
                <Label text="{i18n>AKTIFARAC}" />
                <CheckBox id="aktifAracCheckBoxID" select="onChangeAktifArac"/>

                <Label text="{i18n>ARACTIPI}"/>
               <Input   id="aracModeliInputID"
                        value="{aracBilgileri>/AracTipi}"
                        showValueHelp="true"
                        valueHelpOnly="true"
                        valueHelpRequest="onGetValueHelpMarkaModel"/>

                <Label text="{i18n>MODELYILI}" />
                <ComboBox
                    id="modelYiliComboID"
                    items="{ path:'/CustomizingYilSet' }"
                    selectedKey="{aracBilgileri>/ModelYili}"
                    change="onChangeModelYili">
                    <core:Item key="{Key}" text="{Value}" />
                </ComboBox>

                <Label text="{i18n>SASINO}"/>
                <Input  id="sasiNoID" maxLength="30" value="{aracBilgileri>/SasiNo}"/>

                <Label text="{i18n>SATISTARIHI}"/>
                <DatePicker
                    id="satisTarihiID"
                    value="{path:'aracBilgileri>/SatisTarihi', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true}}"
                    class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>

            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>

        <buttons width="auto" class="sapUiNoMarginBegin
      sapUiNoMarginEnd">
            <Button id="updateButtonID" type="Emphasized"   icon="sap-icon://save" press="onUpdateAracBilgileri" />
            <Button id="createButtonID" type="Emphasized"  icon="sap-icon://add" press="onCreateAracBilgileri" />
            <Button icon="sap-icon://decline" press="aracBilgileriCancel" />
        </buttons>

    </Dialog>



</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: Can you please add some code of the dialog?
In addition you can look on this one if it helps: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.OverflowToolbarButton

Comment: Hi @ShacharW thank you for reply, i put my code but using footer is not possible because there is not a aggreagtion like a footer in sap.m.dilaog component

Comment: Please try to replace <buttons> with <beginButton> or <endButton>.
If it's not working, you could also add a custom css and fix the responsive issue.

Comment: @ümitduran Are you trying to avoid the latter button(s) from being moved into the overflow area? I don't quite get what exactly you mean by "not responsive". Is displaying all buttons without "..." what you want to achieve?